# how to extract data from multiple table in iFrame tag using JSoup

Tags: java, html-table

I need to extract content of multible table in iframe tag,
i'm using this code

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://pubedt.uvsq.fr/VER/g4227.html")
            .header("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0").timeout(100*1000)
            .get();
    for (Element table : doc.select("table")) {
    //    System.out.println(table.html());
        for (Element row : table.select("tr")) {
            Elements tds = row.select("td");
            if (tds.size() > 6) {
                System.out.println(tds.get(0).text() + ":" + tds.get(1).text());
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: But i havn't any Result

Comment: When i try du select iframe i have this message in output D&eacute;sol&eacute; mais votre navigateur ne supporte pas les cadres int&eacute;gr&eacute;s de fichiers XML, ou les cadres int&eacute;gr&eacute;s sont d&eacute;sactiv&eacute;s. Veuillez utiliser le lien ci-dessous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like you are on the right track, but tds.size() never exceeds 6 entries:

```
Document doc = Jsoup
        .connect("http://pubedt.uvsq.fr/VER/g4227.html")
        .header("User-Agent",
                "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0")
        .timeout(100 * 1000).get();
for (Element table : doc.select("table")) {
    // System.out.println(table.html());
    for (Element row : table.select("tr")) {
        Elements tds = row.select("td");
        // log added here
        System.out.println("tds.size(): " + tds.size());
        if (tds.size() > 6) {
            System.out.println(tds.get(0).text() + ":"
                    + tds.get(1).text());
        }
    }
}
```

output:

```
tds.size(): 6
tds.size(): 1
tds.size(): 1
tds.size(): 1
tds.size(): 0
tds.size(): 1
tds.size(): 1
tds.size(): 1
tds.size(): 1
tds.size(): 1
tds.size(): 0
tds.size(): 1
tds.size(): 1
```

Comment: for what When i try du select iframe i have this message in output D&eacute;sol&eacute; mais votre navigateur ne supporte pas les cadres int&eacute;gr&eacute;s de fichiers XML, ou les cadres int&eacute;gr&eacute;s sont d&eacute;sactiv&eacute;s. Veuillez utiliser le lien ci-dessous.
i dont watch the html of ifram in output!!

Comment: use firefox firebug plugin to see what requests are generated, when I use it with your url I see a few requests following the first one for more data, like: http://pubedt.uvsq.fr/VER/g4227.xml and http://pubedt.uvsq.fr/VER/ttss.xsl, the data you are after might be included there